Flutter audioplayers plugin not playing audio from assets despite correct setup

I'm working on a Flutter app where I want to play an audio file (Bonjour.mp3) from the assets when a user clicks on a list item. I'm using the audioplayers package for this, but despite setting everything up, no sound plays when I click the list item. Here’s what I have done so far: Added audioplayers dependency to pubspec.yaml:


 dependencies:
      audioplayers:^6.1.0. 


  assets:
    - assest/voices/Bonjour.mp3



import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Introduction extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntroductionState createState() => _IntroductionState();
}

class _IntroductionState extends State<Introduction> {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  List<Map<String, String>> phrases = [
    {'french': 'Comment vous appelez-vous ?', 'english': 'What is your name?'},
    // more phrases...
  ];

  void playAudio(String phrase) async {
    if (phrase == 'Comment vous appelez-vous ?') {
      await audioPlayer.play(AssetSource('Bonjour.mp3'));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Introduction Phrases")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: phrases.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final phrase = phrases[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(phrase['french']!),
            onTap: () => playAudio(phrase['french']!),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
    

note : i tried in physical device as well no sounds the rest fun is ok but dosent make the sound .[enter image description here][1]
    enter code here

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/KNxJpxGy.png

